# Using DSL , How to add a child element by rule while adding a parent element

Tags: dsl-tools

Using DSL, How to add an element based on adding someother element?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Your question in its present form is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an AddRule: The process is fully described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126258.aspx

Best regards